# How to boost integer on solr query?

Tags: solr

Indexed words:

```
item1:["word1",
"word2",
"word3",
"4",
"5"];
```

Solr query I would like to improve: `q=(4^2)`

The result expected should return `item1`.

Comment: so, what's the problem? i do not get it

Comment: When I use debug=query, my parsedquery always looses every number boosted. If q=(word1^2 4^2), the part 4^2 is lost.

Comment: are you able to get boost for 4, if in your query you have only 4? e.g. q=(4^2)

Comment: No. I am not. Every number I put on the 'q' parameter gets lost.

Comment: okay, could you please provide your schema.xml? and what's your default search field in the solrconfig.xml

Comment: I realize now that every single character as a term is being lost on the query. Is there a way to change it on the schema.xml?

Comment: could you first share it

Comment: Check your query stemming & other filters which possibly remove those characters

Comment: I changed my solr.LengthFilterFactory min from 2 to 1 character and it worked.